# how to write CMakeList.txt to generate an executable file for Android NDK standalone toolchain and OLLVM

Tags: cmake, android-ndk

I've created a Android ndk standalone toolchain and used a generated OLLVM bin/lib to replace the orignal bin/lib. I want to use this toolchain to generate an Android ARM executable file from test.c, but I don't know how to write the CMakeLists.txt. I write it like this:

```
SET(SRC_LIST test.c)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(test ${SRC_LIST})
```

and I run this command:

```
cmake -DOS=ANDROID   
  -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi   
  -DANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN=standalon-toolchain   
  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=android.toolchain.cmake .**  

make -j8
```

but it can only generate an x86-64 executable not Android ARM executable.

What should I do?

Comment: There is some self-contradiction in your words. An NDK standalone toolchain is for one specific ABI only. If you need multiple ABIs, you can generate multiple standalone toolchains.

Comment: What `.**` at the end of your `cmake` invocation means? Is this a path to the **other directory** with your project? Or is this a `.` path, meaning that you build in the same directory with the sources (*in-source build*)?